# Multiple elements with the same type only generates one root

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd, xsd.exe

I have 3 different possible root-elements with different names, let's call them foo, bar and baz.
All these possible root-elements have the same type, simply called fooBarOrBazType.

Now when I generate my class from the XSD's, only the first element is created with fooBarOrBazType. So I could create that type and when I serialize it, it will be called foo. I don't see any generated entries for either bar or baz.

This happens both when all of the root-elements are in the same schema and when they're split into different xsd-files.

Is there any way to generate it so that every differently named element gets its own corresponding class?

Should I use some sort of inheritance so 3 different types are created? How do I fix this inheritance?

I found it out myself, apparently, using:

```
<xs:element name="foo">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="p:fooBarBazType"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

was sufficient.

Comment: it is only one root be allowed in xml Schemas.

Comment: 1 - As I understood you want to have an xml containin <foo>...</foo><bar>...</bar><baz>...</baz>, right?
2 - Can you post your whole xsd document? (or is this your whole xsd?)